# Custom attribute in UserControl (*.ascx)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

Supposing I have a user control like this

```
<MyTag:MyWidget runat="server" />
```

I am wondering if I can do something like

```
<MyTag:MyWidget runat="server" MemberHeight="400" PublicHeight="200" />
```

So that in MyWidget.ascx I can have

```
<div height="<%=IsLoggedIn ? MemberHeight : PublicHeight%>">
```

or something like that...? Because I want the height to vary in each page that is using this widget.

Comment: Have you tried it? It is possible to expose public properties in your UserControl that you can set like if it would be a standard property of UserControl(like Visible) in the aspx markup. These properties must be serializable(f.e. String or Integer).

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Add a public property to the UserControl class something like...

```
 public int MySize { get; set; }
```

Comment: This is the correct answer (though in your case, you'll add two properties named MemberHeight and PublicHeight).

Comment: Seems it's not working if u declare the property as protected. do u know why?

Comment: @Jun1st - `protected` means that only extending classes can access that Property. In this case, it is a different page/control which needs to access the Property.

Comment: at what moment `MySize` property can be accessed, id it binds in aspx page? mean that in `UserControl.Page_Load` method property == null, so where can it be used?

Comment: @Roar Did you find the answer to this?

Comment: How do you add a custom property which will trigger a file selector once used within the aspx markup (just like src attribute for image tags, etc.) ?

Answer (score 16):

You need to define public properties for both items, as such:

```
public int MemberHeight{ get; set; }
public int PublicHeight{ get; set; }
```