# Set a property of a custom user control in the code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I found this question that shows properties on a custom user control (ascx) can be assigned inline as an HTML attribute: [Custom attribute in UserControl (*.ascx)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5239478/266535)

This works great but what about if I register a custom user control on my page and want to set/get attributes from that control in my code behind?

ASPX:

```
<%-- I can assign ActivePage inline and this works fine --%>
<wd:NavBar ID="MyNavBar" runat="server" ActivePage="navbarItem1" />
```

ASPX.CS:

```
        // I need to change the ActivePage 
        if (what == "internal")
        {
            RunInternalComparison();
            MyNavBar.ActivePage = "navbarItem1";
        }
        else if (what == "external")
        {
            RunExternalComparison();
            MyNavBar.ActivePage = "navbarItem2";
        }
```

That's what I want to do but it doesn't work. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do'h! This actually works. I guess Visual Studio wasn't auto generating controls. Simply adding `protected NavBar MyNavBar;` to the top of my Page solved the problem. I hope someone else finds this useful.