# Apply custom ascx attribute to underlying html

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I've seen: [Custom attribute in UserControl (*.ascx)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5239478/custom-attribute-in-usercontrol-ascx) but it doesn't address the scenario I'm working through.

Suppose I have a control

```
<MyTag:MyWrappingWidget runat="server" />
```

That wraps an asp:TextBox.  I want to be able to apply a number of custom attributes (e.g. for google analytics)

```
<MyTag:MyWrappingWidget runat="server" data-mycustom-category="My Category" data-mycustom-action="click" data-mycustom-value="1" data-mycustom-label="My Label"/>
```

and have them applied to the underlying input box - and thus be available to Javascript for processing.

```
<input type="text" data-mycustom-category="My Category" data-mycustom-action="click" data-mycustom-value="1" data-mycustom-label="My Label"/>
```

This works as expected when applying these attributes to the asp:TextBox but not to the control that wraps it.  What do I need to do to the wrapping control to have it work the same way?

*Note: adding a number of properties to MyWrappingWidget would not solve the problem.  These "context-aware" attributes would only have relevance on the page they're used in.  If the control is used on another context, we'd need to use a different set of attributes.  Arguing that design is outside of the scope of this question.. I just need to make it work.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Page_Load of your control put this:

```
    Dim keys As IEnumerator = Me.Attributes.Keys.GetEnumerator()

    While keys.MoveNext

        Dim key As String = keys.Current.ToString

        If key.Contains("data-") Then

            TextBox1.Attributes.Add(key, Me.Attributes(key))

        End If

    End While
```