# How to add custom inner tag in ASP.NET Web UserControl

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net, tags, webusercontrol

I am creating a new Web UserControl in my ASP.NET Web Form project (using VB.NET). Normally, I could add custom attributes to my UserControl like in the solution for this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5239478/custom-attribute-in-usercontrol-ascx).

However, when it comes to the properties of the child controls, the name of each attribute becomes quite long as I tried to include the control name in it.

For example, I have simple user control like this:

```
<%@ Control Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="MyControl.ascx.vb" 
    Inherits="Web.MyControl" %>

<asp:Panel ID="pnl_Filter" runat="server">
    <div class="d-flex row">
        <div class="col-1">
            <asp:Label ID="lbl_Subject" runat="server" Text="Subject" Font-Bold="true" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-5">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_Subject" runat="server" 
                DataSourceID="ods_Subject" 
                DataTextField="subject_name" 
                DataValueField="subject_id">
            </asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ods_Subject" runat="server"
                TypeName="Web.SubjectManager" 
                SelectMethod="GetSubjectList" />
        </div>
        ....
    </div>
</asp:Panel>
```

I wonder if I could create custom inner tag inside my UserControl so, when I place it in parent page, I could do something like this:

```
<uc:MyControl ID="mc_filter" runat="server">
    <LabelProperties Text="Subject" Font-Bold="true" />
    <DropdownProperties DataSourceID="ods_Subject"
        DataTextField="subject_name" 
        DataValueField="subject_id" />
</uc:MyControl>
```